# pandas: Problems with merging multiple data frames to get desired MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have defined 3 simple data frames as follows:

```
dates = [dt.datetime(2015,1,1),dt.datetime(2015,1,2)]
column_names = ['A','B']
data_open = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], index=dates, columns=column_names)
data_close = pd.DataFrame([[5,6],[7,8]], index=dates, columns=column_names)
data_volume = pd.DataFrame([[9,10],[11,12]], index=dates, columns=column_names)
```

When printed they look as follows:

```
print data_open
            A  B
2015-01-01  1  2
2015-01-02  3  4

print data_close
            A  B
2015-01-01  5  6
2015-01-02  7  8

print data_volume
             A   B
2015-01-01   9  10
2015-01-02  11  12
```

What I am looking for is a way to merge all three of them together and get a single DataFrame with MultiIndex that will look like this:

[image: Desired data frame structure]

I am new to Pandas and I looked in documentation and could not find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with specify `keys` and then [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.swaplevel.html) and [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat([data_open, data_close, data_volume], keys=['open', 'close', 'volume'])
df = df.swaplevel(0,1).sort_index()

print df

                    A   B
2015-01-01 close    5   6
           open     1   2
           volume   9  10
2015-01-02 close    7   8
           open     3   4
           volume  11  12
```

And if you want sort by column `A`:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('A'))
df.index = df.index.droplevel(0)
print df

                    A   B
2015-01-01 open     1   2
           close    5   6
           volume   9  10
2015-01-02 open     3   4
           close    7   8
           volume  11  12
```